# ServiceLocatorAwareInterface confuses the DI container when running module tests

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I have a new module for which I'm writing tests.
The module contains a class which implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface because it needs to create other objects using the DI container. Everything works fine when running in the skeleton app, but when running module tests i get the following:

> Zend\Di\Exception\RuntimeException: Invalid instantiator of type "NULL" for "Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface"

Researching a little bit I find that the DI container tries to create a new object of type "ServiceLocatorAwareInterface", which is of course wrong.

Digging a little more in the tests bootstrap, I find that adding the following line solves the problem, as in the DI now knows what class to instantiate for that interface.

```
$di->instanceManager()->addTypePreference('Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface', new \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager());
```

I'm not sure whether this is the best solution to the problem, as the ServiceManager passed by me is a dummy one.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are going in the right direction. (See [the preferences documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.di.instance-manager.html#preferences))

Not many people are using DI these days in favor of the ServiceManager (myself included), but if the config for DI remains similar to how it was during the ZF2 betas, you should be able to add a "preferences" section to your DI config like so:

```
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'preferences' => array(
            'My_Interface' => 'My_Implementation_Or_Alias',
        ) 
    )
)
```

This configuration block can replace your call to `$di->instanceManager()->addTypePreference()`

---

Looking through the current docs, and mimicking the example [here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.di.debugging-and-complex-use-cases.html#multiple-injections-to-a-single-injection-point), you may have success defining the DI config as shown below using the ZF2 official release:

```
$di = new Zend\Di\Di;
$di->configure(new Zend\Di\Config(array(
    'instance' => array(
        'preferences' => array(
            'My_Interface' => 'My_Implementation_Or_Alias',
        ) 
    )
)));
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the SM with factories is the preferred way of creating objects after the betas. Probably I will alter the code later.

Comment: DI is such a novel idea, it is a shame to see it go. If you do want to keep your DI config in the long run, Ocramius on github is a useful source (https://github.com/Ocramius/OcraDiCompiler). He's a big fan of DI.

Comment: I think the main problem with DI in PHP is that it has to be reprocessed on every request and is process intensive right? I'm just guessing here. Sure you can setup caching, but for those of us JUST trying to pickup Zend it isn't that easy to setup. I think that going with the Service manager was a good idea. It makes things more explicit and less 'magical'.

Comment: Yeah. DI uses introspection, which is costly; for production environments, the DI config should be "compiled" into static configuration. With DI, some things "just work", but the benefits are small compared to the added complexity. The SM definitely is more beginner friendly.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this case is the following.

In your bootstrap for the module unit tests create a dummy application that is configured with a configuration that will only load the module you're testing.

```
...//other code before this for autoloading stuff

// DON'T RUN THE application in your tests, just init it
$application = Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/test.application.config.for.module.php');

$fullyConfigedManager = $application->getServiceManager();

TestCases::setServiceManager( $fullyConfigedManager );
```

After the application has been boostrapped you can pull the ServiceManager from the application directly. This service manager should be fully configured with any factories, invokables, and configuration from your module.

Comment: This gets the job done, but it's kind of useless to have a whole application object created. Instead I fixed it by manually creating a SM with the DI inside. Example here: https://github.com/bedeabza/BdzHtmlEmail/blob/master/tests/bootstrap.php